# How do I change jquery code to javascript since Bootstrap will stop supporting jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I copied this *working* code to use on my site but now that bootstrap is going to discontinue JQuery I want to change the below to vanilla javascript.

I'm a beginner and don't fully understand the logic behind it.

Can anyone help me write it in vanilla JS?

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
      if (!o[this.name].push) {
        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
      }
      o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
      o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
  });
  return o;
};

$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
    return false;
  });
});
```

I'm using the JS section of [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/sxGtM/5002/).

Comment: Just because Bootstrap won't use JQuery doesn't mean that browsers won't support it. **JQuery IS JavaScript.** It will never not be supported.

Comment: (At least as long as JavaScript is supported ;)...)

Comment: even if Bootstrap won't use JQuery you can just import it to your website using cdn link or a jQuery file.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple form that doesn't have array names you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API.

Note you will need a polyfill to use `Object.fromEntries()` in some lesser grade browsers

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const res = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
  const json = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4)

  document.querySelector('textarea').value = json;


});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <select name="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  </select>
  <input value="foo" name="text1">
  <input value="" name="text2"> One: <input type="radio" name="radios" value="1"> Two: <input type="radio" name="radios" value="2" checked>
</form>
<hr/>
<strong>Results</strong>
<br/>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```